# Choose a path depending on relationship property on neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationship, cql

All my nodes are 'Places' with only the 'name' property, and I have different relationships named A, B and C, each one of them has a 'cost' property.

If I am at the first node, connected to the second one, I want to 'take' the relationship with the lower cost.

For example:

```
MATCH (p1:Place{name: place1}) 
MATCH (p2:Place{name: place2}) 

MERGE (place1)-[:A{cost: "10"}]->(place2)
MERGE (place1)-[:B{cost: "5"}]->(place2)
MERGE (place1)-[:C{cost: "20"}]->(place2)
```

What Ii want to do, is take (in this case) the relationship B

The costs of the relationships are always the same for the name each one of them (A always costs 10, and B always 5) so maybe it will not be necessary to put the cost property to it).

the best solution is to do it with a query or list the paths and select the best one with java?

Depending on that, how can I do it? and what it would be the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways you can do this.

For few nodes and few relationships, it should be easy enough to order the relationships by cost and grab the first one:

```
...
MATCH path=(:Place{name: place1})-[r]-(:Place{name: place2})
WITH path, r
ORDER BY r.cost ASC
LIMIT 1
RETURN path
```

If this is for a more complex operation, such as calculating a path of least cost between nodes, then this turns into a weighted shortest path query, and you might want to look into solutions using Dijkstra's algorithm. [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) has an [implementation](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_graph_algorithms_work_in_progress) you might use.